# Spring 2.7.0 WebFlux App Context Path is Not woking

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

i am learning Spring web Flux And i want to access to my API but I got 404 even i specify
the path like this spring.webflux.base-path=/tsa/rest in my application.properties.
here is my config :

```
spring.webflux.base-path=/tsa/rest
server.port=8181
```

And this is my POM file. i generated my project via Spring initializer with the latest versions :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tsa</groupId>
    <artifactId>tsa-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tsa-api</name>
    <description>Backend API</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

does anyone have any idea why the base-path is not working in my project? should I decrease my spring boot version? if yes what is the good version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One mistake from my side was; defining 'spring.webflux.base-path' with '@RequestMapping' with the controller. Coz of that, I was getting 404 error. By removing RequestMapping entry, I was able to solve my issue.

One more thing to try is by enabling DEBUG/TRACE web logs 'logging.level.web=TRACE' which would might provide more details.